# Re-Initialize Remote Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver

So I've been trying to re-instantiate my remote webdriver by calling it in a static webdriver extensions class

```
public static void WaitForForm(this RemoteWebDriver rwd, string form)
{
    rwd = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), 
    appCapabilities);
    rwd.WaitUntil(drv => rwd.Title == form);
}
```

I get the following error message:

> An unknown error occurred in the remote end while processing the command.

Comment: Did you check the inner exception and stack trace?

Comment: @shaahin yes unfortunately no more information given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to set DesiredCapabilities every time you re-instantiate the driver. In my case:

```
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", pathToApp);
```